# How to convert a string containing a list of values that are not comma-separated to a list?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm new to Python and am wondering what is the most elegant way to convert a string of the form `"[1 2 3]"` to a list? If the string contains a comma-separated list of values, then the solution is simple:

```
str = "['x', 'y', 'z']"
arr = eval(str)
print isinstance(arr, list) # True
```

However, this solution doesn't work if the list in the string is not comma separated, e.g. `"['x' 'y' 'z']"`.

Is there a common way to solve this without having to manually parse the string? The solution should not be type dependent, e.g. both `"[1 2 3]"` and `"['multiple words 1' 'multiple words 2']"` should be converted normally.

Comment: [.split()](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/dictionary/python-split)

Comment: If you the type of items within the list is supposed to be string best approach is to just strip and split the string. Otherwise, you can replace the spaces with a comma and then use `ast.literal_eval`.

Comment: Where does `str` come from? Why are you reading in data like this?

Comment: @Chris_Rands I get it from a 3rd party library.

Comment: I think you should write your own procedure to parse these kind of strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case shlex might be a solution.

```
import shlex

s = "['x' 'y' 'z']"
# First get rid of the opening and closing brackets
s = s.strip('[]')
# Split the string using shell-like syntax
lst = shlex.split(s)
print(type(lst), lst)

# Prints: <class 'list'> ['x', 'y', 'z']
```

But you'll have to check if it fulfills your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

```
import re

str = "[1 2 a 'multiple words 1' 'multiple words 2' 'x' 'y' 'z']"
print ([''.join(x) for x in re.findall("'(.*?)'|(\S+)", re.sub(r'^\[(.*)\]', r'\1', str))])
>>> ['1', '2', 'a', 'multiple words 1', 'multiple words 2', 'x', 'y', 'z']
```

The first obvious step is to get rid of the `[...]` because they don't add anything useful to the results ...

Then it works because of the regex in `findall`: this will only match either anything between quotes or any sequence of non-spaces.

We don't want the quotes themselves (or do we? – it is not specified) so the regex grouping allows it to return just the inner parts.

Then we always get pairs of one element empty and one filled (`('', '1')`, `('', '2')` and so on) so we need an additional cleaning loop.

This code cannot see the difference between `[1 2 3]` and `['1' '2' '3']`, but that's no problem as such a variant is not specified in the question.

Comment: Thank you for this answer and for the explanation. I accepted Roel Schroeven's answer for brevity, but this one appears to do the job fine as well.